# how to divide product attributes table in sections in magento

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I need to put a group attributes in section 
it means every title attribute are header in product attributes table 
How I can do It 
this my site 
http://select-mob.com/huawei-honor-4c.html

this what I need to do 
https://www.techbeat.mobi/eg_en/huawei-honor-4x.html

Answer (score 0):

You can implement such feature described in following link

[How to display Attribute Group Name on Product page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438750/how-to-display-attribute-group-name-on-product-page)

In that code, first attribute group will be displayed and then all its attributes will be displayed.